# Convert MathType equation in word to MathML

Tags: c#, ms-word, mathml, mathtype

I have some mathtype equations in word that i would like to convert to mathml.  I have tried using the MathType SDK but it kept giving me an exception when trying to call a non managed dll.  I have also emailed the support contacts and have heard nothing back.  I know that word stores the ole.bin and mwf files for the mathtype equations so i was wondering if someone knew how to parse those files to obtain the mathml information.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy-paste the MathML code.

1. Open MathType
2. Select Preferences from the top bar.
3. Click "Cut and Copy Preferences"
4. Change the radio button to select "MathML or TeX" and your preferred standard.

You should be able to Copy the code from MathType (open the equation editor window, highlight, copy) and paste it directly into the code of whatever editor you're using.

Comment: Unfortunately I want to be able to do this programmatically therefore using the MathType client is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having licensed MathType application,

You can download their SDK for .NET from here.

http://www.dessci.com/en/reference/sdk/

Import the DLL and Keep the MT6.DLL in your Project root folder.
And Use ConvertEquation class to convert your MathType Equation to TEX or MathML based on the Translators.

/*edit*/

```
using ConvertEquations; 
private ConvertEquation ce = new ConvertEquation();
ce = new ConvertEquation(); 
String latexText = ce.Convert(new EquationInputFileWMF(pr2.GetInputFolder(imagefile.Name)), new EquationOutputFileText(pr2.GetOutputFile("txt"), Util.MathTypeTranslaterName));
```

This Works for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please explain as step by step how to convert Mathtype equation to MathML. I am new to C#. But I am in need to convert the equation. I could not able to Import the DLL itself as I got the error as " A reference to C:\\..\MT6.dll" could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component". Also kindly note that I have MT6.dll in the "C:\Program Files\MathType\System" folder

Comment: You should have the DLL in the project folder. In my project i have the MT6.DLL in the folder Lib in the csProj file as <Content Include="Lib\MT6.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please let me know the coding for using ConvertEquation class to convert the Mathtype Equation in MS WORD to MathML based on the Translators

Comment: I have added the snippet. Please check it

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. I think the code which you have added converts WMF file (Image file) to MathML. Am I right? But my requirement is to convert ALL Mathtype Equations in Word 2010 to MathML. Could you please able to provide Convert() method parameters to set for converting MathType Equations to MathML

Comment: You have to extract the contents of Docx file(Which is a zip file) and get the wmf file from that. And convert that WMF file to mathml using the code i have provided.

Comment: Thanks for all your support in this regard

Comment: I got the SDK and installed in my system, I tried the below coding to convert Mathtype eps (eps/WMF) to Mathtype eps (eps/none). But I did not get any output file in the path. Kindly check and let me know what is wrong in my coding?  ConvertEquation ce = new ConvertEquation();
            ce.Convert(new EquationInputFileEPS("E:\\Test_Equ\\test.eps"), new EquationOutputFileEPS("E:\\Test_Equ\\output\\test123.eps"));